# Can I set Sitefinity database schema to other than dbo?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I am trying to set database schema to "tts" instead of default "dbo" for Sitefinity Project. But I don't know that this can work or not. Currently my project's database has dbo schema.

Please suggest me how can I change schema to "tts" & sitefinity project keep working well.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't advise so - lot's of unpredictable results may occur. What's your reasoning for this?

Comment: wanted to seperate sitefinity tables from other tables which we have in another database but wanted to merge into sitefinity database so wanted to use a different schema but that is fine if that is not an option,

Comment: all Sitefinity tables are prefixed with sf_ so that's something to distinguish them. Exception of this rule are tables created by the Module Builder - they don't have sf_ prefix

Answer (score 0):

This post is older but you can still use the section outlined for the database:
https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/gabesumner/posts/gabe-sumners-blog/2011/06/02/how_to_deploy_sitefinity_4_to_shared_hosting

Snippet for changing dbo:

```
DECLARE tabcurs CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT 'dbo.' + [name]
      FROM sysobjects
     WHERE xtype = 'u'

OPEN tabcurs
DECLARE @tname NVARCHAR(517)
FETCH NEXT FROM tabcurs INTO @tname

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC sp_changeobjectowner @tname, 'charity'

    FETCH NEXT FROM tabcurs INTO @tname
END
CLOSE tabcurs
DEALLOCATE tabcurs
```